# (Fedora) Anaconda Kickstart - Post Script - Display to GUI

Tags: fedora, gui, kickstart, installer-anaconda

I am looking for a way to display messages to the user within the graphical installer during a kickstart post script.

Nearly all the documentation/questions I have found have successfully explained how to log messages to **console** but I'd like to log them to the gui installer instead.

For example; right now, at the end of the install, it displays "Running post installation scripts..." and instead of that message, I'd like to replace it with messages relating to what is going on within the script.

I found this: https://kickstart-list.redhat.narkive.com/X0Du63Np/display-progress-during-long-kickstart-post-script which seems to allude to some way to get it to display messages but I am not familiar enough with it to figure out how to get it to work.

Does anyone know of a way to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Execute without `chroot`**

You can then take access to Xserver local socket:

```
%post --nochroot 
{
    command 1
    echo -n "10\n# installing some 1 ..."
    
    command 2
    echo -n "20\n# installing some 2 ..."
} | zenity --display=:1 --progress ....
```

**2. In `chroot` environment use a named pipe**

- In `%pre-install` make simple `systemd` service with:

  ```
  mknod /mnt/sysroot/tmp-buf p
  zenity --display=:1 --progress .... < /mnt/sysroot/tmp-buf
  ```
- Add to `%post` script lines like

  ```
  {
  echo -n "10\n# installing some 1 ..."
  ...
  echo -n "40\n# installing some 2..."
  } | tee /tmp-buf
  ```

Comment: wow thanks, i'll have to try that out! I almost forgot about this question :)